# Backbone.js create object from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to create objects like this

```
var classes = {
   A: <object here>,
   B: <object here>,
   ...
};

new classes[name]()
```

However I cannot get it to work in my backbone app.

```
define([
  // Application.
  "app"
],

function(app) {

  var Partials = app.module();

  var classes = {
    'AccountNavStart' : Partials.Views.AccountNavStart = Backbone.View.extend({
       template: 'member/account-nav',
       serialize: function(){
         return { model: this.model };
       }
     })
  };

  // Required, return the module for AMD compliance.
  return Partials;
});
```

and I try to use it like this

```
new Partials.classes['AccountNavStart']()
```

But I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AccountNavStart' of undefined
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning classes? That's the module being defined. Or if you want to add to the Partials Object then you need to do `Partials.prototype.classes = ...`. Otherwise `Partials.classes` is never being defined.

Comment: save `classes` to `Partials` before returning it - `Partials.classes = classes`

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk this works, please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `classes` to `Partials` before returning it:

```
function(app) {
  //...
  Partials.classes = classes;
  return Partials;
});
```